# RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step

Tags: pytorch, huggingface, pytorch-lightning

I'm trying to use [donut](https://github.com/clovaai/donut), which is a transformer model with a huggingface implementation, and pre-train it on a language it hasn't been yet on my desktop. Unfortunately the version of the stack provided on the original repo doesn't support my GPU, so I had to port it to a newer PyTorch/PyTorch Lightning version.

Upon the first run, I got the following error:

```
RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in 
producing the loss returned by training_step. If this is intentional, you must enable 
the detection of unused parameters in DDP, either by setting the string value 
`strategy='ddp_find_unused_parameters_true'` or by setting the flag in the strategy with 
`strategy=DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True)`.
```

Since I haven't really used Lightning before, I'm unsure of what this means. I've managed to get it run by setting said string value to True, but I don't know if I did something wrong while porting or if this is by design.

I've checked the [documentation](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/notebooks/lightning_examples/finetuning-scheduler.html?highlight=find_unused_parameters), but there's very limited information. Setting this to `True` comes with a performance impact, so I'd like to know if I'm doing something wrong or if it's needed.

The training step is defined as follows:

```
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    image_tensors, decoder_input_ids, decoder_labels = list(), list(), list()
    for batch_data in batch:
        image_tensors.append(batch_data[0])
        decoder_input_ids.append(batch_data[1][:, :-1])
        decoder_labels.append(batch_data[2][:, 1:])
    image_tensors = torch.cat(image_tensors)
    decoder_input_ids = torch.cat(decoder_input_ids)
    decoder_labels = torch.cat(decoder_labels)
    loss = self.model(image_tensors, decoder_input_ids, decoder_labels)[0]
    self.log_dict({"train_loss": loss}, sync_dist=True)
    return loss
```

I'll gladly share more code as I'm not sure where the parameters are being checked for this error message. I'd be thankful for any help.